# Issue with Angular UI grid Tree View when working with Typesript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Below is a usual angularJS html sample using ui-grid-tree-view, which renders properly.

```
<div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-tree-view class="grid">
```

when converting the code to typescript, ui-grid-tree-view directive is not rendering, even the pre function in the directive is not being reached.

For typescript code, "gridOptions" is being added as a public var to the controller class. Relevant code sample:

```
export class MyController{
    constructor(){
        this.gridOptions = {
            columnDefs: [
                { name: 'Name', width: '15%' },
                { name: 'Description', width: '15%' },
                { name: 'IsActive', cellTemplate: '<ul ng-if="row.entity.IsActive == true"><li style="color:green"></li></ul><ul ng-if="row.entity.IsActive== false"><li style="color:red"></li></ul>', width: '10%' }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Created the required dataArray for tree view using a recursion function. Using in HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as ctrl"
    <div id="grid1" ui-grid="ctrl.gridOptions" ui-grid-tree-view class="grid"></div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Are you adding the js-files to the html? Are you adding the controller to the module?

Comment: Yes, we are adding js files to html as well as the controller to a module, as required

Comment: And what angular version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set this controller as an `Angular Controller`.

You miss this stuff

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);
myModule.controller('myController', [()=> {new MyController()}]);
```

and @ the html you should write is:

```
ng-controller='myController'
```

You also missed the concept of `$scope`...

Answer (score 0):

I think it was one of my team members who asked this question.. sorry for coming back late.

The issue was resolved after adding the dependency for `ui.grid.treeView` in the angular dependency list.

The portions which @oded recommended are the ones which are not included here in the sample.
Lastly, just to clarify, this is angular 1 to typescript.