# UI Grid - from JavaScript to Typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am fairly new to Angular and just recently constructed this UI Grid table. I used several code examples on the tutorial site at http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/tutorial to build mine. So basically its just the app.js (please see my code below) that I was tasked to convert from Angular JavaScript to Typescript. But since I am new to Angular and Typescript and learn best by example (still going through intro tutorials on Plurasight.com), I need to see one in order to understand how to go about it.

Is there any chance someone could point me to a Plunker link or any other source where I could see an example of Typescript-based code of the app.js/app.ts for UI Grid? I'd greatly appreciate any help!

Actual CODE

```html
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.saveState', 'ui.grid.selection', 'ui.grid.cellNav', 'ui.grid.edit', 'ui.grid.pinning', 'ui.grid.grouping', 'ui.grid.exporter']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.gridOptions = {
        enableCellEditOnFocus: true,
        enableFiltering: true,
        columnDefs: [
            { name: 'skunumber', displayName: 'SKU Number', enableCellEdit: true, width: '125' },
            { name: 'description', displayName: 'SKU Description', enableCellEdit: true, width: '145' },
            { name: 'averagecost', displayName: 'Cost', enableCellEdit: true, width: '65' },
            { name: 'regularretail', displayName: 'Retail', enableCellEdit: true, width: '75' },
            { name: 'saleprice', displayName: 'Sale Price', enableCellEdit: true, width: '100' },
            { name: '%offretail', displayName: '% Off', enableCellEdit: true, width: '75' },
            { name: '$offretail', displayName: '$ Off', enableCellEdit: true, width: '70' },
            { name: 'savings', displayName: 'Savings', enableCellEdit: true, width: '100' },
            { name: 'projunits', displayName: 'Projected Units', enableCellEdit: true, width: '140' },
            { name: 'scandown', displayName: 'Scan $', enableCellEdit: true, width: '75' },
            { name: 'page', displayName: 'Page', type: 'number', width: '65' },
            { name: 'group', displayName: 'Group', type: 'number', width: '75' },
            {
                name: 'pickup', displayName: 'PickUp', editableCellTemplate: 'ui-grid/dropdownEditor', width: '85',
                cellFilter: 'mapPickup', editDropdownValueLabel: 'pickup', editDropdownOptionsArray: [
                    { id: 1, pickup: 'S' },
                    { id: 2, pickup: 'VI' },
                    { id: 3, pickup: 'N/A' }
                ]
            },
            {
                name: 'adcopy', displayName: 'Ad Copy', editableCellTemplate: 'ui-grid/dropdownEditor', width: '125',
                cellFilter: 'mapAdcopy', editDropdownValueLabel: 'adcopy', editDropdownOptionsArray: [
                    { id: 1, adcopy: 'Asst.' },
                    { id: 2, adcopy: 'Asst. sizes' },
                    { id: 3, adcopy: 'Asst. sizes and colors' },
                    { id: 4, adcopy: 'Asst. sizes and counts' },
                    { id: 5, adcopy: 'Asst. styles' },
                    { id: 6, adcopy: 'Big Men sizes $1 more' },
                    { id: 7, adcopy: 'Big Men sizes $2 more' },
                    { id: 8, adcopy: 'BOGO' },
                    { id: 9, adcopy: 'BOGO 50%' },
                    { id: 10, adcopy: 'BTGT for $' },
                    { id: 11, adcopy: 'BTGT FREE' },
                    { id: 12, adcopy: 'Buy this many _, Get for $' },
                    { id: 13, adcopy: 'Buy this many _, Get this many _ free' },
                    { id: 14, adcopy: 'Compare at' },
                    { id: 15, adcopy: 'Coupon Item' },
                    { id: 16, adcopy: 'Limited Qty.' },
                    { id: 17, adcopy: 'Local Low Price' },
                    { id: 18, adcopy: 'Low Price Leader' },
                    { id: 19, adcopy: 'New @ Freds' },
                    { id: 20, adcopy: 'Own Brand Compare and save' },
                    { id: 21, adcopy: 'Plus sizes $1 more' },
                    { id: 22, adcopy: 'Plus sizes $2 more' },
                    { id: 23, adcopy: 'Primary Sale Item' },
                    { id: 24, adcopy: 'SCREAMING LOW PRICE ITEM' },
                    { id: 25, adcopy: 'Styles vary by store' },
                    { id: 26, adcopy: 'While supplies last' },
                    { id: 27, adcopy: 'Your Choice' }
                ]
            }
        ],
        exporterLinkLabel: 'get your csv here',
        exporterPdfDefaultStyle: { fontSize: 9 },
        exporterPdfTableStyle: { margin: [30, 30, 30, 30] },
        exporterPdfTableHeaderStyle: { fontSize: 10, bold: true, italics: true, color: 'red' },
        exporterPdfOrientation: 'landscape',
        exporterPdfPageSize: 'LETTER',
        exporterPdfMaxGridWidth: 500,
        exporterHeaderFilter: function (displayName) {
            if (displayName === 'skunumber') {
                return 'SKU Number';
            } else {
                return displayName;
            }
        },
        exporterFieldCallback: function (grid, row, col, input) {
            if (col.name == 'pickup') {
                switch (input) {
                    case 1:
                        return 'S';
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        return 'VI';
                        break;
                    default:
                        return 'N/A';
                        break;
                }
            }
            if (col.name == 'adcopy') {
                switch (input) {
                    case 1:
                        return 'Asst.';
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        return 'Asst. sizes';
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        return 'Asst. sizes and colors';
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        return 'Asst. sizes and counts';
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        return 'Asst. styles';
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        return 'Big Mens sizes $1 more';
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        return 'Big Mens sizes $2 more';
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        return 'BOGO';
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        return 'BOGO 50%';
                        break;
                    case 10:
                        return 'BTGT for $';
                        break;
                    case 11:
                        return 'BTGT free';
                        break;
                    case 12:
                        return 'Buy this many _, Get for $';
                        break;
                    case 13:
                        return 'Buy this many _, Get this many _ free';
                        break;
                    case 14:
                        return 'Compare at';
                        break;
                    case 15:
                        return 'Coupon Item';
                        break;
                    case 16:
                        return 'Limited Qty.';
                        break;
                    case 17:
                        return 'Local Low Price';
                        break;
                    case 18:
                        return 'Low Price Leader';
                        break;
                    case 19:
                        return 'New @ Freds';
                        break;
                    case 20:
                        return 'Own Brand Compare and save';
                        break;
                    case 21:
                        return 'Plus sizes $1 more';
                        break;
                    case 22:
                        return 'Plus sizes $2 more';
                        break;
                    case 23:
                        return 'Primary Sale Item';
                        break;
                    case 24:
                        return 'SCREAMING LOW PRICE ITEM';
                        break;
                    case 25:
                        return 'Styles vary by store';
                        break;
                    case 26:
                        return 'While supplies last';
                        break;
                    default:
                        return 'Your Choice';
                        break;
                }
            } else {
                return input;
            }
        },

        onRegisterApi: function (gridOptions) {
            $scope.gridOptions = gridOptions;
        }
    };

    $http.get('../../data/global.json')

        .then(function (response) {
            var data = response.data;
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                data[i].registered = new Date(data[i].registered);
                data[i].pickup = data[i].pickup === 'N/A' ? 1 : 3;
                data[i].adcopy = data[i].adcopy === 'Your Choice' ? 1 : 27;
            }
            $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
        });

    // ADD NEW ROW

    $scope.addSku = function () {
        var n = $scope.gridOptions.data.length + 1;
        $scope.gridOptions.data.push({

            "skunumber": n++,
            "description": "SKU description " + n,
            "averagecost": "$" + n + ".00",
            "regularretail": "$" + n + ".00",
            "page": n,
            "group": n,
            "pickup": " ",
            "adcopy": " ",
            "costoverride": "$" + n + ".00",
            "retailoverride": "$" + n + ".00",
            "adunitsper": n,
            "retailunitsper": n,
            "saleprice": "$" + n + ".00",
            "%offretail": "%" + n,
            "$offretail": "$" + n + ".00",
            "savings": "$" + n + ".00",
            "scandown": "$" + n + ".00",
            "combopriceper": "$" + n + ".00",
            "combosaleprice": "$" + n + ".00",
            "comboscandown": "$" + n + ".00",
            "estneedbreakout": n,
            "jdareplenished": true,
            "raincheck": true,
            "shelftalker": true,
            "eventsign": true,
            "projunits": n,
            "projected": "$" + n + ".00"
        });

    };
    // DELETE SELECTED

    $scope.deleteSku1 = function () {
        angular.forEach($scope.gridOptions.selection.getSelectedRows(), function (data, index) {
            $scope.gridOptions.data.splice($scope.gridOptions.data.lastIndexOf(data), 1);
        });
    };
    // DELETE SELECTED - SET GRID API ON SCOPE
    $scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function (deleteSelected) {
        $scope.gridOptions = deleteSelected;
        deleteSelected.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, function (row) {
        });
    };

    // REMOVE TOP ROW
    $scope.removeFirstRow1 = function () {
        $scope.gridOptions.data.splice(0, 1);
    };

    $scope.state = {};

    // SAVE & RESTORE STATE


    // gridOptions SAVE
    $scope.gridOptions.saveState = function () {
        $scope.state = $scope.gridOptions.saveState.save();
    };
    // gridOptions RESTORE
    $scope.gridOptions.restoreState = function () {
        $scope.gridOptions.saveState.restore($scope, $scope.state);
    };

    $scope.export = function () {
        if ($scope.export_format == 'csv') {
            var myElement = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll(".custom-csv-link-location"));
            $scope.gridOptions.exporter.csvExport($scope.export_row_type, myElement);
        } else if ($scope.export_format == 'pdf') {
            $scope.gridOptions.exporter.pdfExport($scope.export_row_type);
        }
    };

}])

    .filter('mapPickup', function () {
        var pickupHash = {
            1: 'S',
            2: 'VI',
            3: 'N/A'
        };
        return function (input) {
            if (!input) { return 'pickup'; }
            else { return pickupHash[input]; }
        };
    })

    .filter('mapAdcopy', function () {
        var adcopyHash = {
            1: 'Asst.',
            2: 'Asst. sizes',
            3: 'Asst. sizes and colors',
            4: 'Asst. sizes and counts',
            5: 'Asst. styles',
            6: 'Big Mens sizes $1 more',
            7: 'Big Mens sizes $2 more',
            8: 'BOGO',
            9: 'BOGO 50%',
            10: 'BTGT for $',
            11: 'BTGT free',
            12: 'Buy this many _, Get for $',
            13: 'Buy this many _, Get this many _ free',
            14: 'Compare at',
            15: 'Coupon Item',
            16: 'Limited Qty.',
            17: 'Local Low Price',
            18: 'Low Price Leader',
            19: 'New @ Freds',
            20: 'Own Brand Compare and save',
            21: 'Plus sizes $1 more',
            22: 'Plus sizes $2 more',
            23: 'Primary Sale Item',
            24: 'SCREAMING LOW PRICE ITEM',
            25: 'Styles vary by store',
            26: 'While supplies last',
            27: 'Your Choice'
        };

        return function (input) {
            if (!input) { return 'adcopy'; }
            else { return adcopyHash[input]; }
        };
    });
```

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid     Under the Compatibility section, you can see that UI Grid is only compatible with AngularJS 1.6. Hence not Angular 2. and not Typescript

Comment: There're developers who're looking into it, apparently it's possible? Since I'm novice & don't have in-depth expertise yet, was hoping someone could kindly share an example?

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/3720

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32112911/issue-with-angular-ui-grid-tree-view-when-working-with-typesript

There're issues with it but it looks like some folks are actually able to transition it to TS, but I am at loss how to bite into it without seeing a code example (similar to those found at http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/tutorial) that illustrates the concept.

Comment: UI grid working with Typescript. Doesn't mean UI grid is compatible with Angular 2/4/5. And for beginners, there are grid libraries that's compatible with Angular 2 and above. "Trying to make it work or write some kind of wrapper' are approaches for people who are migrating an entire application from Angular 1 to 2. And they rely on some existing functionalities. In another word, if you are learning UI grid, then install AngularJS 1.6